# Correct and portable way to serialize an enum

Tags: c++, c

I need to serialize enum values to be sent over the network. The sending part in in C and runs on an 8-bit micro-controller, with no Protocol Buffers or similar library available. The receiving part is in C++ (Linux). I tried following approach:

```
enum enum_x {
    V1 = 1,
    V2 = 2,
};

enum enum_y {
    V3 = 1,
    V4 = 2,
    V5 = 3,
};

enum enum_z {
    V6 = 1,
    V7 = 2,
    V8 = 3,
};

uint8_t serialize_enums(enum_x x, enum_y y, enum_z z) {
    return x * 100 + y * 10 + z;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be valid. It works OK on my Linux box, but the result is incorrect on an 8bit system (the y value seems to be stored as z and z value is missing). I tried to add casts:

```
return (uint8_t)x * 100 + (uint8_t)y * 10 + (uint8_t)z;
```

but it did not help. What is the correct approach?

Comment: "the result is incorrect on an 8bit system" - just to be clear, you're saying that on your 8 bit system `serialize_enums(V1, V3, V6)` returns `101`?

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense :)

Comment: And also that `serialize_enums(V1, V4, V8)` returns `102`. How do you determine this? If you replace the call to `serialize_enum` with just an integer with the "right answer", `111` or `123`, does whatever debugger/output/flashing LED that you used to see the 101/102 start showing 111/123?

Comment: Investigate the C code-generators for protobuf's: [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) and [nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/nanopb/).

Comment: I tested like this: serialize_enums(V1, V3, V6) I got 101 decimal, when I changed to serialize_enums(v1, v5, V6) I got 103 decimal (so the change in the second argument seems to be affecting the least significant decimal digit). I'm checking this by sending serialized value over the network, when I hardcoded the value to be sent to be for example 133, it is sent correctly.

Comment: @Jan: OK, I'll grant you that is properly weird. Next thing is to disassemble the 8bit code, see what it's actually doing. There is no way that any C compiler should compute `1 * 100 + 1 * 10 + 1` to be anything other than `111`, no matter what types the numbers are or the sizes of the types. Converting the result to `uint8_t` is fine for your range of values.

Comment: The only simple change I can think of that would make your code do what you observe is if it's somehow really `return x * 100 + y * 1;0 + z;`. There isn't any macro-trickery going on in your real code, is there, that could hide a typo like that?

Comment: No, there are no macros around this code. Do you think that this approach is valid in general and should work, and if it doesn't it must be caused by something else, not improper serialization code?

Comment: @JanWrobel: yes, I think the code you've shown here is fine. Since `x` only goes up to `2` and `y` to `3`, it's a valid way to pack your three values into a `uint8_t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop it turned out you were right. The problem was not caused by incorrect serialization. The cause was that library that defined serialization function was compiled with -fshort-enums flag (gcc) and it was linked to the code that used the function but was compiled without -fshort-enums. But binaries compiled with and without the flag are not compatible and should not be linked together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send them in an `8-bit` field, allow for values between 0-3 for each `enum`, I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct s_enum_t
{
   s_enum_t(
      int x,
      int y,
      int z)
      : x_(x)
      , y_(y)
      , z_(z)
   {}

   union
   {
      struct
      {
         uint8_t x_ : 2;
         uint8_t y_ : 2;
         uint8_t z_ : 2;
         uint8_t spare_ : 2;
      };
      uint8_t val;
   };
};

int main()
{
   s_enum_t v(1, 1, 1);

   std::cout << v.val << "\n";
}
```

That will get the values laid out in a very specific manner.  When sending between different systems you have to be aware of the endian scheme for each system though.

To clarify, with each individual enumerated value laid out in `2-bits`, it becomes easier to troubleshoot issues between the sending and receiving systems.  In this particular case, you have to be familiar with how this will be laid out on each system (by the compiler) to know how to properly decode the values. Having individual values in a bitfield that can be printed out (for debugging purposes) allows you to easily identify which fields are which when doing the initial system integration testing.

Comment: "a very specific manner" - very specific but implementation-dependent. It's not really about endian-ness, the order of bit fields within a byte is a separate thing.

Comment: True, but in this case you have to be familiar with how each system you are communicating with will "see" the data.  If each value has two bits in the field, it becomes easier (in my opinion) to troubleshoot the issue that it would to serialize into a single "large number".

Comment: The thing is that I need it to work in C and C++ so it needs to be C.